# When to Update ALSA Audio Driver Buffer Pointer

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, alsa

I am writing an `USB Audio Playback` driver using `ALSA APIs`. For that I was trying to understand existing audio drivers in `Linux` kernel. But I get confused on when to update the kernel audio buffer pointer. We know kernel puts new audio data in a ring buffer and our drivers task is to take new data from the ring buffer, pass it over USB and update the kernel buffer pointer.

The drivers I was looking at takes care of this in `URB` completion function. Say they have a predefined macro for USB transfer size, which is around `4096` bytes in almost all cases. So when the `URB` transfer is finished and the code execution path comes in `URB` completion, they copy another `4096` bytes from the kernel buffer into the `URB` buffer, submit the `URB` again to the `USB` controller and forward the kernel buffer pointer by `4096` bytes.

But what I don't understand is, how come they be so sure that by the time a `URB` trasfer is finished, there are `4096` bytes of new data in the kernel buffer? The new data amount in the kernel buffer might be smaller than `4096` bytes? Then why does it always update the buffer pointer by `4096` bytes. I think there should be some of knowing how many new bytes are in the kernel buffer and the driver should only  update by that amount or may be I misunderstood something? Any suggestion or guideline is appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These USB audio drivers behave exactly like a PCI sound card, i.e., when the device needs some samples, those samples are just read from the ring buffer.

A PCI chip has no way of knowing what part of the buffer actually contains valid samples.
A buffer underrun is detected later by software (the device informs the driver about the current position with an interrupt; the interrupt handler then raises the underrun error if the position is too far ahead).

USB audio drivers use exactly the same mechanism for detecting underruns, i.e., the `snd_pcm_period_elapsed()` function checks whether the current position (as returned by your `.pointer` callback) is too far ahead.

Comment: Thanks CL. That Answers my question. Just need to clear up a few things. You said the USB drivers use the snd_pcm_period_elapsed() function to check whether the current position is too far ahead. So if it is too far ahead, how does it solve that problem? Do we have to do something from the our driver to solve that or ALSA takes care of that?

Comment: ALSA takes care of stopping the stream, or doing whatever is configured.